# Wrong DateTime field (+1 hour) in a Telerik RadGrid with Odata client binding

Tags: javascript, json, datetime, telerik, odata

I'm using a RadGrid (but I think the problem is not with the grid itself) with client binding to a service with Type = Odata, ResponseType = JSON.
With Fiddler, when I see the Raw Detail of the call to my service I can see: **"LogDate": "/Date(1417796043643)/"**

Correct me if I'm wrong, this number is the DateTime converted to the milliseconds from 01/01/1970.

All the algorithm I found googling around (and the telerik grid too) are converting this number to: 05 December 2014 17:14:03.

But in my DB the value of  'LogDate'  field of the table where the service is reading from, is 16:14:03!!

As far as I understood the "Date" javascript object takes in input an UTC Date and automatically adds the 'offset' of my timezone ( I'm GMT+1 ) and this is where the +1 hour comes from! (maybe? :D)

Hoping I explained myself well. Any solution? Maybe an event where i can intercept the JSON response (OnRowCreating?) and manupulate myself?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the Date object shows your local timezone. Are the dates stored in your DB UTC? This problem is common and most of the asnwers suggest using only UTC dates thoughout your entire application. Hope this helps

Comment: Ye... I guessed so. We are storing in our DB the actual local time, not a 'converted UTC' one! :/
So the Date object is thinking it's a UTC Date and adds the +1 of my timezone.
A suggested 'clean' solution that doesn't involve changing all the Dates stored in DB? :D